# Unable to connect to IMAP Server using IMAPClient

Tags: java, email, connection, imap, apache-commons-net

I am trying to connect to the gmail's IMAP / SMTP server.

I can connect whitout problems to the SMTP server (`smtp.gmail.com:587`), but not to the IMAP server (`imap.gmail.com:993`). The stacktrace of the exception just says that the connection was closed.

Imagine the fictitious `main` class like this:

```
public class Main{

    public void main(String[] args) {
        MailDomains domainChecker = new MailDomains();
        domainChecker.pingServer("smtp.gmail.com:587", "imap.gmail.com:993");
    }
}
```

This is my code

```
public HashMap<String,Boolean> pingServer(String smtp_address, String imap_address) {
    HashMap<String, Boolean> areConnected = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    IMAPClient imapClient = new IMAPClient();
    SMTPClient smtpClient = new SMTPClient();

    //Comprobación SMTP
    try {
        //smtp_address -> [HOSTNAME]:[PORT] (already checked the substring's)
        smtpClient.connect(
                smtp_address.substring(0, smtp_address.indexOf(':')),
                Integer.parseInt(smtp_address.substring(smtp_address.indexOf(':')+1,smtp_address.length())));

        areConnected.put("smtp", smtpClient.isConnected());
        smtpClient.disconnect();
        l.info("Conectado satisfactoriamente al servidor SMTP");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        l.error("Dirección SMTP errónea. Host inaccesible");
        areConnected.put("smtp", false);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Comprobación IMAP
    try {
        //imap_address -> [HOSTNAME]:[PORT] (already checked the substring's)
        imapClient.connect(
                imap_address.substring(0, imap_address.indexOf(':')),
                Integer.parseInt(imap_address.substring(imap_address.indexOf(':')+1,imap_address.length())));

        areConnected.put("imap", imapClient.isConnected());
        imapClient.disconnect();
        l.info("Conectado satisfactoriamente al servidor IMAP");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        l.error("Dirección IMAP errónea. Host inaccesible");
        areConnected.put("imap", false);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    smtpClient = null;
    imapClient = null;

    return areConnected;
}
```

It takes a moment until it throws the IMAP related exception. This is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException: Connection closed without indication.
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.__getReply(IMAP.java:151)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP._connectAction_(IMAP.java:227)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAPSClient._connectAction_(IMAPSClient.java:175)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:244)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:306)
at Utils.MailDomains.pingServer(MailDomains.java:81)
at interfaz.controller.AddServerMailController.registerAddress(AddServerMailController.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas about what is going on? I searched on internet but there is not much documentation, or atleast, i couln't find it. I would appreciate it if you post some article about this.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your stack trace, btw.

Comment: I could make it run on my laptop so it looks like a problem with the jvm configuration settings or stuff like that. Still not being able to work on my desktop pc because of this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you turning on SSL for the imap connection.  Port 993 is SSL/TLS secured IMAP port.

Comment: How can i set that feature?

Comment: So i definitely should acquire the SSL certificate. I have read [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105746) but i need to do it programmatically. Is there some way to get the certificate through the imap address?

Comment: Oops, this is Java IMAPClient.  Sorry, was looking at the wrong docs!

Comment: A quick browse through apacke commons net looks like you would set the socket factory on IMAPClient before connecting. so you should set it to an SSLSocketFactory.  This bit seems underdocumented to me.

Comment: Or use IMAPSClient: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/imap/IMAPSClient.html